Ambiguous Azure OpenAI model retirement date
it is unclear which is the correct Azure OpenAI model retirement date.
I have different retirement dates under Azure OpenAI Studio (oai.azure.com) and on the Azure Learn (learn.microsoft.com).
The model where I see this ambiguity is gpt-35-turbo model version 0301.

Under the Azure Learn help page the retirement date is January 27, 2025.

Under Azure OpenAI Studio > Deployments the retirement date is 11/1/2024.


Which one is correct?
(Asking here because Azure community support points here)

In my environment, retirement dates showing jan 27 2025 in deployments https://i.imgur.com/aohbcuL.png
